# Word search game : grid generating takes too long

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I'm working on a Word Search puzzle game, and I'm struggling with generating the grid with letters. At the moment, I'm able to generate the grid, but the performance is very slow (way too slow for a decent usage, it can take up to 30-40 seconds before generating the grid).

To fit words into the grid, I'm using a recursive function that tries to fit the last word from a given list, then the one before it, etc, and if it doesn't fit, backtracks to the previous word and changes its place, then tries again. I guess I'm not doing this right, because it keeps going back and forth.

I tried to use weighed probabilities for directions, so that the generating is made in a "smarter" way, but I'm not getting any results yet.

**My question :**
How can I optimize this code to make it more performant and reliable? I accept any suggestions, even if it makes me do a lot of changes (if there is an iterative solution for example instead of a recursive one, or if I'm not reasoning correctly in the function...).

Here is the function:

```
function tryWord(grid, wordList, index, gridLength){
    var valid = false;
    var clear = false;

    if(index==(wordList.length-1)){
        /* Clear grid for current index */
        for(var j=0; j<gridLength.x; j++){
            grid[index][j] = [];
            for (var k=0; k<gridLength.y; k++){
                grid[index][j][k] = '';
            }
        }
        var nbIterations = 0;
        // Try current word
        while(valid == false){
            // Impossible to resolve this grid
            if(nbIterations>500){
                return false;
            }
            nbIterations++;
            var initX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridLength.x); // x coord of first letter of the word
            var initY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridLength.y); // y coord of first letter of the word
            var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8); // direction of the word (0=top-left; 1=top; 2=top-right; 3=right; 4=bottom-right; 5=bottom; 6=bottom-left; 7=left)

            valid = checkValidWord(wordList[index].length, initX, initY, direction, gridLength);
        }

        clear = checkClearWord(wordList[index], initX, initY, direction, grid[index]);
        if(!clear){
            return false;
        }

        var x = initX;
        var y = initY;
        for(var j=0; j<wordList[index].length; j++){

            grid[index][x][y] = wordList[index].charAt(j);
            switch(direction){
                case 0:
                    x--;
                    y--;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    y--;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x++;
                    y--;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x++;
                    y++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    y++;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    x--;
                    y++;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    x--;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
    else if(index!=(wordList.length-1)){
        var emptyGrid = true;
        for(var p=0; p<grid[index].length; p++){
            for(var q=0; q<grid[index][p].length; q++){
                if(grid[index][p][q]!=''){
                    emptyGrid = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(emptyGrid || $scope.nbIterations>50){
            $scope.nbIterations=0;
            grid = tryWord(grid, wordList, index+1, gridLength);
        }
        /* Prepare grid for current index */
        grid[index] = grid[index+1];
        if(grid!=false){
            // Try current word
            while(valid == false){
                var initX = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridLength.x); // x coord of first letter of the word
                var initY = Math.floor(Math.random() * gridLength.y); // y coord of first letter of the word
                var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8); // direction of the word (0=top-left; 1=top; 2=top-right; 3=right; 4=bottom-right; 5=bottom; 6=bottom-left; 7=left)

                valid = checkValidWord(wordList[index].length, initX, initY, direction, gridLength); // Check that word fits in the grid

            }

            clear = checkClearWord(wordList[index], initX, initY, direction, grid[index]);
            // If word is obstructed by other words
            if(!clear){
                $scope.nbIterations++;
                return tryWord(grid, wordList, index, gridLength); // Try again
            }
            else{
                var x = initX;
                var y = initY;
                for(var j=0; j<wordList[index].length; j++){                   

                    grid[index][x][y] = wordList[index].charAt(j);
                    switch(direction){
                        case 0:
                            x--;
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            x++;
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            x++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            x++;
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            x--;
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            x--;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return grid;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Parameters of the function :**

- `grid` : at the beginning, just a 10x11x11 array filled with '' string.
- `wordList` : an array of words to put in the grid
- `index` : 0 when calling the function for the first time, then it's used to check how deep we are in the wordList
- `gridLength` : an array : {x:11, y:11}, giving the grid length

**Some more precisions about the function :**

- The function `checkValidWord` checks if a given word going to a given direction fits in a grid with a given size. Returns true or false.
- The function `checkClearWord` checks if a given word going to a given direction fits in the grid with other words already in it (no obstruction etc). Returns true or false.
- The function `tryWord` is supposed to output **a 3-dimensional array** of size [wordList.length;11;11]. I then use the grid[0] as my 2 dimensional grid for the game.

Comment: Can you show an example of a desired output?

Comment: I edited my question => This function outputs a 3-dimensional array, I take the first element of it (it's the only interesting one, as the other ones were only useful for backtracking during the recursion) as a 2-dimensional grid which I then display to the player.

Comment: I mean an actual example of the output, are you thinking of something like [this](https://cdn.education.com/worksheet-image/180324/cities-word-search-travel-games.gif) ?

Comment: How many words need to be in the grid? are you stopping after a certain percentage of the grid is filled with word, i can imagine that filling the last couple grid points is kinda of hard. It might be better to fill the last 10% of the grid with random letters, and then check if the letters make or finish words.

Comment: @SaiBot: Yes absolutely, that's the output I get.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander: 10 words need to be in the grid, and some of them are pretty long, that's why I guess it influences the performance. I tried with a 13x13 grid (same number of words) and it's already better.

Comment: Possibly you need something like Knuth shuffle instead of `while (count< tooManyAttempts) {Math.random()}`.